# Sort string containing text and numbers

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query and sort a column without much luck. My data looks like this and is consistent with the preceding "WP".

Should display as

```
  WP1-WP2
    WP2-WP3
    WP10-WP11
    WP10-WP12
```

Actually displays as

```
 WP1-WP2
    WP10-WP11
    WP10-WP12
    WP2-WP3
```

I've attempted adapting several answers found on here with no success.

Question is how do I sort this list as it should??

EDIT: I am using distinct in the query, not sure if this will effect the problem I'm having

Comment: @juergen d Thanks, I was in the middle of doing that :)

Comment: Which is your database? SQL Server, MySql, Oracle etc.

Comment: MySQL according to 000webhost's website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 select *
 from myStringSorting
order by Cast(Replace(Substring(mycol,0,CHARINDEX('-',mycol)),'WP','') as Int) asc
        ,Cast(Replace(Substring(mycol,CHARINDEX('-',mycol) + 1,LEN(mycol)),'WP','') as Int) asc
```

Check out this link, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca45f/5

With DISTINCT,

```
With CTE as
(
select distinct mycol
 from myStringSorting
 )
 select * from CTE
order by Cast(Replace(Substring(mycol,0,CHARINDEX('-',mycol)),'WP','') as Int) asc
        ,Cast(Replace(Substring(mycol,CHARINDEX('-',mycol) + 1,LEN(mycol)),'WP','') as Int) asc
```

With DISTINCT, without CTE, using sub query,

```
Select a.mycol from
(
select distinct mycol
 from myStringSorting
 )as a
order by Cast(Replace(Substring(a.mycol,0,CHARINDEX('-',a.mycol)),'WP','') as Int) asc
        ,Cast(Replace(Substring(a.mycol,CHARINDEX('-',a.mycol) + 1,LEN(a.mycol)),'WP','') as Int) asc
```

Comment: Syntax problem, not sure what ver SQL is being used, using 000webhost.

Comment: Corrected, please check.

Comment: SQL query: Documentation 

SELECT DISTINCT WP
FROM btsec
WHERE Estimate = 'IBH39WMT'
ORDER BY Cast( Replace( Substring( WP, 0, CHARINDEX(

'-', WP
) ) , 'WP', '' ) AS Int ) ASC , Cast( Replace( Substring( WP, CHARINDEX(
 '-', WP
) +1, LEN(
WP
) ) , 'WP', '' ) AS int ) ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30 

MySQL said: Documentation 
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Int) asc,Cast(Replace(Substring(WP,CHARINDEX('-',WP) + 1,LEN(WP)),'WP','') as in' at line 1

Comment: It doesn't seem to like what comes after CHARINDEX( from ' onwards

Comment: Where are you executing this code? SQl Fiddle or your server?

Comment: Why you have DISTINCT still in your select?

Comment: I'm in phpMyAdmin. I'm using distinct as as the data is replicated many times in that column and I'm only want 1 of each different field displayed.

Comment: It is Distinct causing the issue using your code. Since I'll be using this in PHP I can use your code and then use array_unique to clean up after.

Comment: I have edited ans. & added code with Distinct also. please check

Comment: Tried on server end and didn't work. My host is using MySQL. I adapted your code to make the with command work. Not sure what else needs changing to make it work. `select * from (select distinct WP from btsec where Estimate='IBH39WMT') AS dataset order by Cast(Replace(Substring(WP,0,LOCATE('-',WP)),'WP','')as Int,Cast(Replace(Substring(WP,LOCATE('-',WP) + 1,LEN(WP)),'WP','')as Int`

Comment: again updated!, this will be my last try, I think I should learn syntax of MySql asap.

Comment: haha I appreciate your help. This has been a cosmic pain in the hole to fix what should be something really simple. BTW it didn't work on MySQL :D

Answer (score 1):

Another method

```
select * from myStringSorting
order by len(mycol),mycol
```

Comment: I have tried this one and it did throw and error. `#1547 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted`

Comment: `LENGTH(mycol),mycol` works but `LEN(mycol),mycol` doesn't. Fussy version of SQL on the server it seems